# How can I loop recursive multiple regression models in a list?

Tags: r

Afternoon.
I'm quite new to R, stuck with how to construct looping code

I am trying to implement forward selection method by hand to decide which ARDL model yields the best in terms of maximizing Rsquared

Compared to the null model (which only includes lags of dependent variable)
I am adding one more explanatory variable in RHS (from x1 to x100) and see which model with one of the extra variables is the best. After deciding the best model (e.g. adding x4 to the null model), then add one more from the model, and see which extra variable improves the goodness of fit. And so on.

I am stuck how to recursively add regression models in a list for each step.

In my data,
`tr.y.nm[,1]` is unemployment rate (574 by 1)
`tr.x.nm` is 574 * 100 ts matrix (100 explanatory variables, monthly periods = 574, already did `ts()` command for these data)

e.g `head(tr.y.nm[,1])`

```
        Mar  Apr  May  Jun  Jul  Aug
 1959  -0.3 -0.4 -0.1 -0.1  0.1  0.1
```

e.g `head(tr.x.nm)`

```
              IPS11       IPS299        IPS12        IPS13        IPS18        IPS25
 Mar 1959  0.006036378  0.004895892  0.000000000  0.019390148 -0.004744042  0.010748331
 Apr 1959  0.014336262  0.014545480  0.015655235  0.006386045  0.016509317  0.025786451
 May 1959  0.008271245  0.009580762  0.004766352  0.020148842  0.000000000  0.031894446
 Jun 1959  0.007031562  0.007127874 -0.004766352  0.007452366 -0.007040905  0.023276858
 Jul 1959  0.001167806  0.008248732  0.013057215  0.019610733  0.008209585  0.002187639
 Aug 1959 -0.007023326 -0.002348087  0.001177440 -0.028310578  0.011614957 -0.008787931
 (omitted)
```

Null model

```
fm0 <-tr.y.nm[,1]~L(tr.y.nm[,1],1:4)
summary(dynlm(formula=fm0))$r.squared
```

Model 1

```
fm1 <- tr.y.nm[,1]~L(tr.y.nm[,1],1:4)+ L(tr.x.nm[,x[1]], 0:1)
```

Model 2

```
fm2<- tr.y.nm[,1]~L(tr.y.nm[,1],1:4)+ L(tr.x.nm[,x[1]], 0:1) + L(tr.x.nm[,x[2]],0:1)
```

Model 3

```
fm3<- tr.y.nm[,1]~L(tr.y.nm[,1],1:4)+ L(tr.x.nm[,x[1]], 0:1) + L(tr.x.nm[,x[2]],0:1) + L(tr.x.nm[,x[3]],0:1)
```

Something like that.

So what I want is 100 formulas (Model 1 ~ Model 100) and

Model 2 is adding **`L(tr.x.nm[,x[2]]`** to Model 1

Model 3 is adding **`L(tr.x.nm[,x[3]]`** to Model 2

It would be better if I can make a list of 100 that contains these models so that I can apply `summary(dynlm())` and extract Rsquared from each element of the list.

Maybe function `paste` and `lapply` will help but I cannot come up with clear solutions.

I'd appreciate if you can help me!!!